# Moving item in QML GridView

Tags: gridview, drag-and-drop, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have following code with GridView. Rectangles inside are draggable. When I drag and drop some rectangle within GridView, dragged rectangle replaces the one from drop zone, but also all other rectangles between (which have indexes between dragged and dropped) reordering their position.
Is it possible to make that dragged item exchanges position only with item placed on dropped zone?

```
import QtQml.Models 2.2
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 360
    height: 360

    signal changePosition

    GridView {
        id: root
        width: 320
        height: 480
        cellWidth: 80
        cellHeight: 80

        property int lastChangedIndex: -1
        property int xAxis: 0
        property int yAxis: 0

        displaced: Transition {
            NumberAnimation {
                properties: "x,y"
                easing.type: Easing.OutQuad
            }
        }

        model: DelegateModel {
            id: visualModel
            model: ListModel {
                id: colorModel

                ListElement {
                    color: "blue"
                    itemNumber: "0"
                }
                ListElement {
                    color: "green"
                    itemNumber: "1"
                }
                ListElement {
                    color: "red"
                    itemNumber: "2"
                }
                ListElement {
                    color: "yellow"
                    itemNumber: "3"
                }
                ListElement {
                    color: "orange"
                    itemNumber: "4"
                }
                ListElement {
                    color: "purple"
                    itemNumber: "5"
                }
                ListElement {
                    color: "cyan"
                    itemNumber: "6"
                }
                ListElement {
                    color: "magenta"
                    itemNumber: "7"
                }
            }

            delegate: MouseArea {
                id: delegateRoot

                property bool held: false
                property int visualIndex: DelegateModel.itemsIndex

                width: 80
                height: 80

                drag.target: held ? icon : undefined

                onPressAndHold: {
                    held = true
                    icon.opacity = 0.5
                }
                onReleased: {
                    if (held === true) {
                        held = false
                        icon.opacity = 1
                        icon.Drag.drop()
                    } else {
                        //action on release
                    }
                }

                Rectangle {
                    id: icon
                    width: 50
                    height: 50
                    anchors {
                        horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                        verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    }
                    color: model.color
                    radius: 3

                    Text {
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        text: model.itemNumber
                    }

                    Drag.active: delegateRoot.drag.active
                    Drag.source: delegateRoot
                    Drag.hotSpot.x: 36
                    Drag.hotSpot.y: 36

                    states: [
                        State {
                            when: icon.Drag.active

                            ParentChange {
                                target: icon
                                parent: root
                            }

                            AnchorChanges {
                                target: icon
                                anchors.horizontalCenter: undefined
                                anchors.verticalCenter: undefined
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }

                DropArea {
                    id: dropArea

                    anchors {
                        fill: parent
                        margins: 15
                    }

                    signal trigger

                    Timer {
                        id: dropZoneTimer
                        interval: 1000
                        onTriggered: {
                            dropArea.trigger()
                        }
                    }
                    onTrigger: {
                        visualModel.items.move(drag.source.visualIndex,
                                               delegateRoot.visualIndex)
                        root.lastChangedIndex = delegateRoot.visualIndex
                    }

                    onEntered: {
                        if (drag.source.visualIndex !== delegateRoot.visualIndex) {
                            dropZoneTimer.start()
                        }
                    }
                    onExited: {
                        dropZoneTimer.stop()
                        root.lastChangedIndex = -1
                    }
                    onDropped: {
                        if (root.lastChangedIndex !== delegateRoot.visualIndex) {
                            visualModel.items.move(drag.source.visualIndex,
                                                   delegateRoot.visualIndex)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The way that I'd probably do this is to swap the values of the model items, rather than actually *move* them:

```
import QtQml.Models 2.2
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 360
    height: 360

    GridView {
        id: root
        width: 320
        height: 480
        cellWidth: 80
        cellHeight: 80

        displaced: Transition {
            NumberAnimation {
                properties: "x,y"
                easing.type: Easing.OutQuad
            }
        }

        model: DelegateModel {
            id: visualModel
            model: ListModel {
                id: colorModel

                ListElement {
                    color: "blue"
                    itemNumber: "0"
                }
                ListElement {
                    color: "green"
                    itemNumber: "1"
                }
                ListElement {
                    color: "red"
                    itemNumber: "2"
                }
                ListElement {
                    color: "yellow"
                    itemNumber: "3"
                }
                ListElement {
                    color: "orange"
                    itemNumber: "4"
                }
                ListElement {
                    color: "purple"
                    itemNumber: "5"
                }
                ListElement {
                    color: "cyan"
                    itemNumber: "6"
                }
                ListElement {
                    color: "magenta"
                    itemNumber: "7"
                }
            }

            delegate: MouseArea {
                id: delegateRoot

                property bool held: false
                property int visualIndex: DelegateModel.itemsIndex

                width: 80
                height: 80

                drag.target: held ? icon : undefined

                onPressAndHold: {
                    held = true
                    icon.opacity = 0.5
                }
                onReleased: {
                    if (held === true) {
                        held = false
                        icon.opacity = 1
                        icon.Drag.drop()
                    } else {
                        //action on release
                    }
                }

                Rectangle {
                    id: icon
                    width: 50
                    height: 50
                    anchors {
                        horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                        verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    }
                    color: model.color
                    radius: 3

                    Text {
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        text: model.itemNumber
                    }

                    Drag.active: delegateRoot.drag.active
                    Drag.source: delegateRoot
                    Drag.hotSpot.x: 36
                    Drag.hotSpot.y: 36

                    states: [
                        State {
                            when: icon.Drag.active

                            ParentChange {
                                target: icon
                                parent: root
                            }

                            AnchorChanges {
                                target: icon
                                anchors.horizontalCenter: undefined
                                anchors.verticalCenter: undefined
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }

                DropArea {
                    id: dropArea

                    anchors {
                        fill: parent
                        margins: 15
                    }

                    onDropped: {
                        var sourceColor = colorModel.get(drag.source.visualIndex).color;
                        var sourceNumber = colorModel.get(drag.source.visualIndex).itemNumber;

                        var targetColor = colorModel.get(delegateRoot.visualIndex).color;
                        var targetNumber = colorModel.get(delegateRoot.visualIndex).itemNumber;
                        colorModel.setProperty(drag.source.visualIndex, "color", targetColor);
                        colorModel.setProperty(drag.source.visualIndex, "itemNumber", targetNumber);
                        colorModel.setProperty(delegateRoot.visualIndex, "color", sourceColor);
                        colorModel.setProperty(delegateRoot.visualIndex, "itemNumber", sourceNumber);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

This assumes that the usage of the `itemsIndex` property (via `visualIndex`) is correct.

Comment: Can not access ' DelegateModel'