# Drag and drop is not working as i t should in qml where the model is a DelegateModel with DelegateModelGroups

Tags: qml, kde-plasma

I have used the code for Drag and Drop from this question  [Moving item in QML GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34754479/moving-item-in-qml-gridview)
but it is not working in my programm.I have the below errors :

**file:///home/christoforos/Videos/launchpadPlasmaMod/contents/ui/AllApps.qml:151:11: QML MyDelegateModel (parent or ancestor of DelegateModelGroup): move: from index out of range**

and

**file:///home/christoforos/Videos/launchpadPlasmaMod/contents/ui/AllApps.qml:260: TypeError: Cannot read property 'visualIndex' of null**

when i try to drag and drop an icon in the`GridView`.As mentioned in the title the model of the `GridView` is a `DelegateModel` with `DelegateModelGroups`.The code  of the model is this:

```
//MyDelegateModel.qml

import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQml.Models 2.4
DelegateModel {
    property int from: 0
    property int to: 10
    groups: [
        DelegateModelGroup {
            id: newItems
            name: "new"
            includeByDefault: true
            onCountChanged: {
                newItems.setGroups(from, to - from, ["new","visible"]);
            }
        },
        DelegateModelGroup {
            id: visibleItems
            name: "visible"

        }

    ]
    filterOnGroup: "visible"
}
```

The code of the `GridView` is this:

```
  GridView {

    id: mainGrid
    cellWidth: 195
    cellHeight: 155

    anchors.fill: parent

    property int lastChangedIndex: -1
    property int xAxis: 0
    property int yAxis: 0

    displaced: Transition {
            NumberAnimation {
                properties: "x,y"
                easing.type: Easing.OutQuad
            }
        }


    model:MyDelegateModel{

        id:visualModel

        from:index*35

        to:Math.min(from + 35, appsModel.count)

        model:appsModel

        delegate: MouseArea{

            id: delegateRoot

            property bool held: false
            property int visualIndex:index

            width: mainGrid.cellWidth-45; height: mainGrid.cellHeight-45;

            drag.target: held ? box : undefined

            onClicked:{

                executable.exec("$(gtk-launch " + appsModel.get(index).display + ")") ;

                console.log(appsModel.get(index).display)
            }

            pressAndHoldInterval : 200

            onPressAndHold: {
                    held = true
                    box.opacity = 0.5
                    box.z = 10
                }
            onReleased: {
                    if (held === true) {
                        held = false
                        box.opacity = 1
                        box.Drag.drop()
                        box.z = 1

                    } else {
                        //action on release
                    }
                }

            Kirigami.Icon {
                id: box
                parent: mainGrid
                x: delegateRoot.x; y: delegateRoot.y-10;
                width: delegateRoot.width;
                height:delegateRoot.height;
                source: appicon

                Text {
                    anchors.top: parent.bottom
                    anchors.horizontalCenter:parent.horizontalCenter
                    text: name
                    font.pixelSize: 12
                    color:"black"
                }

                    Drag.active: delegateRoot.drag.active
                    Drag.source: delegateRoot
                    Drag.hotSpot.x: 36
                    Drag.hotSpot.y: 36

                SequentialAnimation on rotation {
                     NumberAnimation { to:  4; duration: 60 }
                     NumberAnimation { to: -4; duration: 120 }
                     NumberAnimation { to:  0; duration: 60 }
                        running: delegateRoot.held
                        loops: Animation.Infinite; alwaysRunToEnd: true
                }
                    states: [
                        State {
                            when: box.Drag.active
                            ParentChange {
                                target: box
                                parent: mainGrid
                            }

                            AnchorChanges {
                                target: box
                                anchors.horizontalCenter: undefined
                                anchors.verticalCenter: undefined
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }

                DropArea {
                    id: dropArea
                    anchors {
                        fill: parent
                        margins: 15
                    }

                    signal trigger

                    Timer {
                        id: dropZoneTimer
                        interval: 1000
                        onTriggered: {
                            dropArea.trigger()
                        }
                    }
                    onTrigger: {
                        visualModel.items.move(drag.source.visualIndex,
                                               delegateRoot.visualIndex)
                        mainGrid.lastChangedIndex = delegateRoot.visualIndex
                    }

                    onEntered: {
                        if (drag.source.visualIndex !== delegateRoot.visualIndex) {
                            dropZoneTimer.start()
                        }
                    }
                    onExited: {
                        dropZoneTimer.stop()
                        mainGrid.lastChangedIndex = -1
                    }
                    onDropped: {

                        if (mainGrid.lastChangedIndex !== delegateRoot.visualIndex) {
                            visualModel.items.move(drag.source.visualIndex, delegateRoot.visualIndex)                        }
                        console.log("drag from",drag.source.visualIndex,"drop to",delegateRoot.visualIndex )

                    }
                }
              }
           }
        }
```

I tried to "debugg" for the last day but nothing.Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: For starters, you should put the `console.log` to before you do the move, not after. That way, you can see the debug message before you hit the error.

Comment: When  I move ```console.log(drag.source.visualIndex,delegateRoot.visualIndex)``` before i make the move, meaning in ```onPressAndHold``` signal I get  the error :* *TypeError: Cannot read property 'visualIndex' of undefined* *.Any suggestions?

Comment: Finally I replace the line ```visualModel.items.move(drag.source.visualIndex, delegateRoot.visualIndex)``` with ```appsModel.move(drag.source.visualIndex, delegateRoot.visualIndex,1)``` in ```onDropped``` signal in ```DropArea``` and I set ```property int visualIndex:index``` and now the ```Drag and Drop``` is working in all ```pages```.